# SQL group by id then group the results by date

Tags: mysql

I have the following sql statement which works however I then want to group the results by YEAR(updated_at), MONTH(updated_at) and give me a total by month of the year. What that should then do is find me all results where order_id exists more than once then to do a total for each month of the year. I think I will need to do a subquery but everything I have tried throws an error.

```
SELECT  `order_id` ,  `updated_at` , COUNT( * ) AS grand_total1
                FROM mg_sales_flat_shipment_track
                GROUP BY  `order_id` 
                HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
                ORDER BY updated_at DESC
```

The data set:

```
entity_id parent_id order_id track_number   title   carrier_code created_at          updated_at
    31468     33349    36055 31237970006263 UK Mail trackerl     2015-05-01 19:30:52 2015-05-01 19:30:52
    31453     33348    36054 31237970006264 UK Mail trackerl     2015-05-01 19:30:49 2015-05-01 19:30:49
    31414     33347    36052 31237970006273 UK Mail trackerl     2015-05-01 19:30:20 2015-05-01 19:30:20
    31469     33346    36050 31237970006265 UK Mail trackerl     2015-05-01 19:30:52 2015-05-01 19:30:52
    31461     33345    36049 31237970006266 UK Mail trackerl     2015-05-01 19:30:47 2015-05-01 19:30:47
    31406     33344    36048 31237970006267 UK Mail trackerl     2015-05-01 19:30:14 2015-05-01 19:30:14
    31404     33343    36047 31237970006268 UK Mail trackerl     2015-05-01 19:30:13 2015-05-01 19:30:13
    31407     33342    36046 31237970006269 UK Mail trackerl     2015-05-01 19:30:15 2015-05-01 19:30:15
    31462     33341    36045 31237970006270 UK Mail trackerl     2015-05-01 19:30:48 2015-05-01 19:30:48
    31405     33340    36044 31237970006271 UK Mail trackerl     2015-05-01 19:30:14 2015-05-01 19:30:14
    31383     33153    35837 31237970006197 UK Mail tracker1     2015-04-30 20:00:43 2015-04-30 20:00:43
    31252     33153    35837 31237970006051 UK Mail tracker1     2015-04-29 20:00:25 2015-04-30 20:00:43
```

Comment: I think you might have to use select month(updated_at) as month, year(updated_at) as year and then say GROUP By order_id,month

Comment: could you tell me which errors you got so I could help you more specifically?

Comment: Thanks for the status report. Did you have a *question*? NOTE: In the query shown, the value returned for the `updated_at` column is *not* deterministic. (Other databases will throw an error with this SQL, and we could get MySQL to throw an error too, if we set `sql_mode` to include `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.)  Showing an *example* of the relevant column values from the table, and showing an *example* of the expected resultset would provide a clearer specification. It would be even better if you would setup a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: @spencer7593 I have updated the question with some more data

Answer (score 0):

Your query as it stands will provide you with unreliable results, as `updated_at` is not included in the `group by` clause, nor is it used in an aggregate function.

If what you want is for all `order_ids` with more than one entry, get a count per month of the year, then it would look something like this:

```
select year(updated_at) y, month(updated_at) m, count(*) from
(  SELECT  `order_id` , COUNT( * ) AS grand_total
                FROM mg_sales_flat_shipment_track
                GROUP BY  `order_id` 
                HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
) q1
inner join mg_sales_flat_shipment_track t
  on q1.order_id = t.order_id
group by year(updated_at), month(updated_at)
order by year(updated_at) desc, month(updated_at) desc;
```

In order to get any further help, you would need to supply your table definition, some sample data, and the results you are trying to extract.

[fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6315f/2)

Comment: I have added an image showing the table structure I don't think theres something adding up correctly is it possible that its counting everything twice?

Comment: @WillWright i don't see any duplicated `order_ids` in that data - which means this query should never return any results. What did you mean by `order_id` exists more than once?

Comment: sorry I have only shown a snippet the table has 31192 rows

Comment: if you could add in some of the duplicate rows, that'd be nice

Comment: I have added a duplicate row to the bottom of the data set

Comment: @WillWright i've added a fiddle to the answer - can you look at it and tell me how that info differs from what you want?  There are 4 `order_ids` that were used in 2015, and again in 2016, hence it counts 4 in each group.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77020/discussion-between-will-wright-and-pala).

Comment: 2015-06 should count 1 as the order_id is duplicated only once it seems to be counting unique order_id's

Comment: @WillWright there are i'm not sure how you expect a count of 1 - there are four order_ids used in 2015-05 that are also used in 2015-06, so you get a count of four for each month. If 2015-06 should only show a count of 1, how many should show for 2016-05?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking for is a resultset like the one returned by a query like this:

```
SELECT o.order_id
     , DATE_FORMAT(o.updated_at,'%Y-%m') AS `yyyymm`
     , COUNT(1)                          AS `cnt`
  FROM ( SELECT d.order_id
            FROM mg_sales_flat_shipment_track d
           GROUP BY d.order_id
          HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
       ) c
  JOIN mg_sales_flat_shipment_track o
    ON o.order_id = c.order_id
 GROUP
    BY o.order_id
     , DATE_FORMAT(o.updated_at,'%Y-%m')
```

Let's unpack that a bit.  The inline view `c` basically gets us a list of `order_id` values that appear more than once. Because of the `GROUP BY`, that's going to be a *distinct* list (one row per `order_id`).

We can join the rows from that inline view (MySQL calls it a "derived table") back to the table, to get all the rows that have an `order_id` that matches one in the list.  We expect that for every `order_id` value, we're going to get at least two rows from the original table.

We use the DATE_FORMAT function to get the year and month. We do a GROUP BY on that, and get the count for each month.

---

If you need the "grand total", we could include a `COUNT()` in the inline view, and then reference that column in the SELECT list of the outer query. That "grand total" of the order_id will be duplicated on every row for the order_id.

**FOLLOWUP**

*it doesn't give me a total for each month*

It's not clear what you want to total.

You could omit the `order_id` column from the SELECT list and the ORDER BY clause in the outer query. That would give you a "count" of rows by "month", of all rows where the `order_id` appears on more than one row.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(o.updated_at,'%Y-%m') AS `yyyymm`
     , COUNT(1)                          AS `cnt`
  FROM ( SELECT d.order_id
            FROM mg_sales_flat_shipment_track d
           GROUP BY d.order_id
          HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
       ) c
  JOIN mg_sales_flat_shipment_track o
    ON o.order_id = c.order_id
 GROUP
    BY DATE_FORMAT(o.updated_at,'%Y-%m')
```

At this point, I'm still just guessing at what resultset you want returned.

Comment: I have updated this fiddle with your suggestion http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/449f4/1 it doesnt give me a total for each month?

Comment: @WillWright: It's not clear what you want to total. You could omit `order_id` from the SELECT list and the GROUP BY. That would give you a "total" by month. (That would be a *count* of rows from the table that have an `order_id` that is duplicated (appears more than once) in the table.